# How to make a .bat file not ask you when you delete something?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

If I put

```
del "\Users\Chris\example"
```

...it says "are you sure you want to delete yes? Y/N?"

Is there way it can just delete the file, without asking me?

Comment: What exactly you trying to explain? Please make it clear .. Your Question Body is not appropriate please simplify it.. Welcome to Stack OverFlow

Comment: @user3390915 - how about you accept an answer if it solved your problem - this is how Stackoverflow works - don't be a freeloader.

Answer (score 2):

del /F /Q should do it... You should really do HELP DEL - as this is just in the manual

```
Deletes one or more files.

DEL [/P] [/F] [/S] [/Q] [/A[[:]attributes]] names
ERASE [/P] [/F] [/S] [/Q] [/A[[:]attributes]] names

  names         Specifies a list of one or more files or directories.
            Wildcards may be used to delete multiple files. If a
            directory is specified, all files within the directory
            will be deleted.

/P            Prompts for confirmation before deleting each file.
/F            Force deleting of read-only files.
/S            Delete specified files from all subdirectories.
/Q            Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to delete on global wildc
/A            Selects files to delete based on attributes
              attributes    R  Read-only files            S  System files
            H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archi
            -  Prefix meaning not
```

Answer (score 1):

```
del /Q
```

From `del /?`

```
/Q            Quiet mode, do not ask if ok to delete on global wildcard
```

Comment: That will delete all subdirectories - is this what he wants?

Comment: @Trent - wanted to say `/Q`

Comment: Looks like you've edited from /S to /Q - ignore my above comment